# Time Limit Exceeded in SPOJ BITMAP

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search

For problem (http://www.spoj.com/problems/BITMAP/). I am using Optimized approach as given on (https://medium.com/@arkro/spoj-bitmap-71d7a12354b1#.smnrwxcjv).

Following is my solution ==>

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
class BITMAP {
    public static void print()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
        }       
    }
    public static void bfs(int i1, int j1, int l)
    {
        a[i1][j1]=l;
        int p[] = {-1,0,1};
        Queue<Integer> qu = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        qu.add(i1);qu.add(j1);
        while(!qu.isEmpty())
        {       
            int i= qu.remove();
            int j= qu.remove();
            for(int m=0;m<3;m++)
            {
                for(int n=0;n<3;n++)
                {
                    int dist = Math.abs(p[m])+Math.abs(p[n]); 
                    if((i+p[m] >-1 && i+p[m]<r) && (j+p[n] >-1 && j+p[n]<c) && a[i+p[m]][j+p[n]]>a[i][j]+dist)
                    {
                        a[i+p[m]][j+p[n]] = a[i][j]+dist;
                        qu.add(i+p[m]);qu.add(j+p[n]);                      
                    }                   
                }           
            }       
        }
    }
    public static int a[][]= new int[182][182];
    public static int r;
    public static int c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        while(t--!=0)
        {
            r = in.nextInt();
            c = in.nextInt();
            ArrayList<int[]> l = new ArrayList<int[]>(); //Using it for storing all 1's location in the entire grid.

            for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
            {
                String str = in.next();
                for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
                {                  
                    if(str.charAt(j)=='1')
                        l.add(new int[]{i,j});
                    a[i][j]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }               
            }

            for(int[] k:l)
                bfs(k[0],k[1],0);   
            print();
            in.nextLine();
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

What should i do for removing this TLE problem ?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1

The approach described in the linked article is inefficient. It starts a BFS traversal from each vertex marked with `1` on the board. The traversal explores each board vertex that has not been reached by a previous BFS with fewer steps. This may lead to some vertices being explored multiple times.

Consider the following example:

```
1000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000001
```

There are two vertices marked with `1`. The first BFS would be started from the `1` in the top-left corner. It would explore the entire board, noting for each vertex the distance to the starting vertex. The second BFS would be started from the `1` in the bottom-right corner. It would explore half of the board, until reaching the vertices that are closer to the `1` at the top-left than to the `1` at the bottom-right. Therefore, half of the board has been traversed twice.

This problem is further amplified the more `1`s there are on the board. Consider for example this board:

```
1111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000
```

The first BFS will traverse the entire board. The second BFS has to explore the entire board except for the first column (the only place on the board that is closer to the first `1` than the second `1`). The third BFS again explores the entire board except for the first two columns, and so on.

There is an easy fix for this problem: Instead of performing a separate BFS for each `1`, you can do a single BFS, starting from all `1` vertices simultaneously. This can be done by initializing the BFS queue with the `1` vertices.

The BFS then continues as usual: It will go through the `1` vertices that are at the beginning of the queue and append their unvisited neighbors to the end of the queue. Therefore, after all `1` vertices have been removed from the queue, the BFS then explores the vertices that have distance one from any `1` vertex. After that, it will explore the vertices that have distance two from any `1` vertex, and so on.

This way, the board only has to be explored once, instead of exploring parts of the board multiple times.

### Problem 2

Besides the time-out problem, there is also a correctness issue in your implementation: It does a 8-way traversal of the board, instead of a 4-way traversal (meaning you go straight and diagonally, instead of only straight).

The metric used in the problem description is the [Manhattan metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), which measures the distance between two points by summing their distance on each axis. Therefore, two horizontally or vertically adjacent points have distance 1, but two diagonally adjacent points have distance 2. So when you allow your BFS to travel diagonally, you incorrectly measure the distance between diagonally adjacent points to be 1 instead of 2.

To fix this, restrict your BFS from taking diagonal steps.